# Given the following table of values (list of numbers congruent to 1 or 5 mod 6) is there a formula to represent the value at the $i^{th}$ iteration

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

As the question states, how can we determine the value at the $i^{th}$ iteration of the following list of numbers congruent to 1 or 5 mod 6:

- 1
- 5
- 7
- 11
- 13
- 17
- 19
- ...

Comment: Many formulas are given here: http://oeis.org/A007310, and the first one is the simplest: $$a_n = \frac{6n + (-1)^n - 3}2$$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $a_n=3n-2$ if $n$ is odd and $3n-1$ if $n$ is even

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you separate them into odd-indexed terms and even-indexed terms, you can observe two arithmetic progression.

$1,7,13,\ldots$ can be written in the form of $g(n)=a_1+(n-1)d_1=1+6(n-1)$.

$5,11,17, \ldots$ can be written in the form of $h(n)=a_2+(n-1)d_2=5+6(n-1)$.

We want to construct the function \begin{align}f(n) &= \begin{cases} g(k) , & n =2k-1 \\ h(k), & n=2k\end{cases}\\ &= \begin{cases} g\left(\frac{n+1}2\right) , & n =2k-1 \\ h\left(\frac{n}2\right), & n=2k\end{cases}\\
&=\begin{cases} a_1+\left(\frac{n-1}2\right)d_1 , & n =2k-1 \\ a_2+\left(\frac{n-2}2\right)d_2, & n=2k\end{cases}\\
&=\begin{cases} 1+\left(\frac{n-1}2\right)6 , & n =2k-1 \\ 5+\left(\frac{n-2}2\right)6, & n=2k\end{cases}\\
&=\begin{cases} 3n-2 , & n =2k-1 \\ 3n-1, & n=2k\end{cases}\\
&=3n-\frac{3}2+(-1)^n\frac12\end{align}